# Is there a name for this type of food (matambre arrollado) in English?

Tags: translation

[Matambre arrollado](https://cookpad.com/ar/recetas/121243-matambre-arrollado) is a type of meat filled with bacon, eggs, carrots, green peas, red bell pepper, green bell pepper, pepper, parsley, chili pepper.

Does this type of food have a name in English?

Comment: In the UK we have ***gala** [pork] **pies*** with egg as well as cured pork in a "hot water crust" pastry filling. But generally speaking we don't have anything like "Matambre arrollado" - so if it ***was*** on sale anywhere here (assuming it could pass Health & Safety regulations) we'd probably use the "native" name for it.

Comment: (*Chez moi*, we have something called "leftover pie" about once a week, containing just about everything lying around in the fridge. But we don't cut it into slices like salami.)

Answer (score 2):

We do not have precisely that cut of beef in the UK, no idea about other Anglophone countries, so there will not be an exact equivalent for us. That style of dish is called a roulade using a French word. So if you said it was a beef roulade (or pork roulade) people would probably imagine something similar. Roulade also has the benefit of being similar to arrollado of course.

Comment: That's probably the best word we've got (or the best word the *French* have got, since we don't have one! :) But if I asked any of my fellow countrymen here in the UK what "roulade" means, I bet most of those who had any idea at all would say it was either (sponge-cake or ice-cream) "swiss roll" or a kind of garlicky cream cheese "sliced" from a roll.

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes I agree it is a word more familiar in other contexts. Translating food names is a minefield.

Comment: A former colleague of mine used to make a roulade of soft meringue. Before we British started using the French word, though, such a dish might have been called a roll (not to be confused with a bread roll) or [roly-poly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jam_roly-poly).

Comment: @KateBunting I did wonder about beef roll but apart from the ambiguity of bread roll stuffed with beef I think a beef roll might be like a meat loaf - minced meat.